# Parsing .js page python

Tags: javascript, python, parsing

I have a webpage http://timetable.ait.ie/js/filter.js and I seriously need to parse this page. I have been using BeautifulSoup over the past few days to parse html pages and I really get what I am doing there but this .js file is killing me.

At the moment I am using the following code:

```
import urllib
page = urllib.urlopen("http://timetable.ait.ie/js/filter.js")
pageInfo = page.read()
```

and it is returning a string with the whole file of 18283 lines of code. In the code I am trying to get the staff names towards the bottom, there is an array:

```
staffarray[373][0] = "BRADY, DAMIEN";
staffarray[373][1] = "SCI";
staffarray[373][2] = "BRADY001608";
```

I need the value from [0] and from [1] and then build a database with these values that I can reference later.

I have tried regex to find the staffarray but I am completely frustrated trying to get this information. Is there anyone that can help me please.

Comment: urllib and requests reads only data from serve. BS lets you find tag in HTML - ie tag <script> with JavaScript code. But you need standard string function or regex to find anything in JavaString code.

Comment: if you have problem with regex then use standard string function - first split file into lines and then find line with `staffarray[` - ie `if "staffarray[" in line:`. And then you can easily find interesting values using other string functions or slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problem with regex then use standard string functions and slicing.

First split code into lines and later search `staffarray[` and `[0]` or `[1]`. Lastly use slicing.

```
import urllib

req = urllib.urlopen("http://timetable.ait.ie/js/filter.js")
lines = req.read().split('\n')

for x in lines:
    if 'staffarray[' in x:
        if '[0] = ' in x:
            start = x.find('"')+1
            end = -3
            print '0', x[start:end]
        elif '[1] = ' in x:
            start = x.find('"')+1
            end = -3
            print '1', x[start:end]
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the help @furas

Answer (score 1):

You could write a regexp pattern with capturing groups:

```
import re
with open('filter.js') as file:
    pattern = r'staffarray\[(?P<first_index>\d+)\]\s*\[(?P<second_index>\d+)\] = "(?P<name>.+)"'
    for line in file:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            first_index, second_index, name = match.groups()
            # do something with data
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer got sorted a while back.